# Can't write to GL_RGBA32UI FBO texture on OpenGL ES

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, glsl

I have two `GL_RGBA32UI` FBO textures, which I use to store current state of particle positions/velocities per texel.

The first I fill with data like this only once:

```
Gdx.gl.glTexImage2D(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL30.GL_RGBA32UI, width, height, 0, GL30.GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, buffer);
```

Per render loop the second one is written to via a shader while the first is used as texture and the second as target. I do that by drawing a quad of from `[-1, -1]` to `[1, 1]` while the viewport is set between `[0, 0]` and `[textureSize, textureSize]`. This way, in the fragment shader I have a shader run per texel. In each run I read the first texture as input, update it and write it out to the second texture.

Then I render the second FBO's texture to the screen using a different shader and mesh, where every texel would be represented by one vertex in the mesh. This way I can extract the particle position from the texture and set `gl_Position` accordingly in the vertex shader.

After that I switch the first and second FBO and continue with the next render loop. This means that the two FBOs are used as a GPU based storage for render data.

**This works totally fine on the desktop app and even in the Android emulator. It fails on real Android devices though: The second FBO's texture of the particular loop has always the values `[0, 0, 0, 0]` after update on real Android devices only. It totally works fine when just rendering the data from the first buffer, though.**

**Any idea?**

My update shaders (take first FBO's texture and render it to the second's) are as follows.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

in vec2 a_vertex;
out vec2 v_texCoords;

void main()
{
    v_texCoords = a_vertex / 2.0 + 0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(a_vertex, 0, 1);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;
precision mediump usampler2D;

uniform usampler2D u_positionTexture;
uniform float u_delta;

in vec2 v_texCoords;
out uvec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    uvec4 position_raw = texture(u_positionTexture, v_texCoords);

    vec2 position = vec2(
        uintBitsToFloat(position_raw.x),
        uintBitsToFloat(position_raw.y)
    );
    vec2 velocity = vec2(
        uintBitsToFloat(position_raw.z),
        uintBitsToFloat(position_raw.w)
    );

    // Usually I would alter position and velocity vector here and write it back
    // like this:
    // position += (velocity * u_delta);
    //
    // fragColor = uvec4(
    //  floatBitsToUint(position.x),
    //  floatBitsToUint(position.y),
    //  floatBitsToUint(velocity.x),
    //  floatBitsToUint(velocity.y));

    // Even with this the output is 0 on all channels:
    fragColor = uvec4(
        floatBitsToUint(50.0),
        floatBitsToUint(50.0),
        floatBitsToUint(0.0),
        floatBitsToUint(0.0));

    // Even writing the input directly would not make the correct values appear in the texture pixels:
    // fragColor = position_raw;
}
```

How I update the textures (from fbo1 to fbo2):

```
private void updatePositions(float delta) {
  fbo2.begin();
  updateShader.bind();
  Gdx.gl20.glViewport(0, 0, textureSize, textureSize);
  fbo1.getColorBufferTexture().bind(0);
  updateShader.setUniformf("u_delta", delta);
  updateShader.setUniformi("u_positionTexture", 0);
  Gdx.gl20.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
  Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ZERO);
  updateMesh.render(updateShader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
  fbo2.end();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are reading a 32-bit per component texture you need a `highp` sampler and you need to store the result in a `highp` variable.

Currently you are specifying a `mediump` for `usample2D` and the default `int` precision is also `mediump`. For integers `mediump` is specified as "at least" 16-bit, so either of these may result in your 32-bit value being truncated.

Note the "at least" - it's legal for an implementation to store this at a higher precision - so you may find "it happens to work" on some implementations (like the emulator) because that implementation chooses to use a wider type.

Comment: Thank you, that made an end to my multi-day misery. But I think there still is not the whole truth as it was enough to add `precision highp int;` to use 32-bit precision for int data. All other precisions, even for `usamler2d` I could set to even `lowp` and it still works. I put everything to `highp`, though.

Comment: The precision of `mediump` is specified "at least 16-bit" for integers, so the actual behavior you're getting with a `mediump` sampler is at the mercy of the implementation. It would be perfectly legal for it to truncate to 16-bit.